# 404 page not showing URL

Tags: php, html, 404

My 404 page (`/404.php`) works, it's sending the proper headers (404 - Not found).

But the thing is, it's not giving the link that caused it (e.g. `example.com/thisisnon-existant.htm`) but instead it's giving my 404 page (`example.com/404.php`).

How would I get it fixed?

All I did was add the following to *.htaccess*:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.php
```

My 404 page's code is here: http://pastebin.com/G7mQ4aT1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the full url for ErrorDocument, Apache will **always** issue a redirect to that location.  You want to change your ErrorDocument directive to a relative path instead.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I fell so dumb. Thanks man. I'd never thought to use that because every thing I read said "ALWAYS USE DIRECT PATH, NEVER RELATIVE PATHS"

Answer (score 3):

Stephen answered your question spot on, but another observation regarding your example code that you linked to, that you might want to remove these lines in your PHP code:

```
<?php
  header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Your web server already responded with 404 when this document would be used and you're just providing a nicer to read error document. There is no need for this document to add a response header indicating 404 error like you did, when it would already be included in a server's response following a request for non-existent location/document.

Comment: Setting the header (again) is redundant, but it won't "trigger a further 404 server error".

Comment: Whilst this might be a useful tip, it doesn't actually help answer the OP's question.

Comment: What was happening it was a soft 404, I didn't want google to see it as a page, so I added that for a temp fix, I'm still testing it.

Comment: Ok, I removed the code and it sends a 404 header and everything works. Thanks!